# Have a regex that matches either one character or two different characters, same on both sides

Tags: regex

Okay so I have an input which contains several sequences that are either surrounded by double quotes "word" or french quotes « word »

The thing is, french quotes must have a space on both sides separating the word from the quotes.

So I have to match, at the beginning of the word, either (") or (« ).

Right now, I have this:

```
(« |“)([^»”]+)( »|”)
```

I would like my word in the middle to be my only output, but using this technique I get three outputs ($1, $2 and $3), and only the second one is relevant.

So I'm looking for a way to do this without using parenthesis.

Comment: Good question being specific about not wanting to use parenthesis.  I've added an answer that does just this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your regex:

1. more than 1 capture group (which is the question you are asking)  This can be solved by using non-capturing group

   ```
   (?:« |“)([^»”]+)(?: »|”)
   ```

   so you only have 1 capture group `$1` which contains the word you want
2. It is matching things like `«hello”`.  This is a bit tricky.  You may use positive look-forward to make sure the quotes appears in pairs:

   ```
   (?=«.*»|“.*”)(?:« |“)([^»”]+)(?: »|”)
   ```

Check a demo in regex101: https://regex101.com/r/OD10hz/1

---

Edit:  After giving a second thought, there seems to be an even easier alternative:

```
(?<=« ).*(?= »)|(?<=“).*(?=”)
```

The match (`\0`) itself is what you are looking for.  It is also easier to add support for other quote-pair type, and it match things like `“A»B”` correctly.

Comment: Was going to DV this, but I'll just comment: I don't think you should be loosening up match criteria.  It could be counter-Intuitive

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "loosening up match criteria".  It was what OP using.  And my 2nd point is actually tightening the match criteria to avoid unmatched quotes (which OP admits it is a problem in comment in another answer)

Comment: I didn't know OP mentioned that.  +1 on your answer.  Good work

Comment: This is perfect. Even though the other answers answered my original question, I'll accept this one because it went one step further and solved the other problem pointed out by some other answers. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In many flavors of regex (you don't specify what you're using), the syntax supports non-capturing groups, which typically begin with `(?:` and end with `)`:

```
(?:« |“)([^»”]+)(?: »|”)
```

Separately, note that your regex would incorrectly match strings like

```
“Hello! »
« Bonjour!”
```

Comment: I hadn't noticed that problem. Is there a way to solve it without repeating the content of the word twice in the regex?

Comment: Here are two options: if your engine supports backreferences, you could do that. Otherwise, just alternate between two whole regexes, one each for english and french quotes.

Comment: @ravron there is a 3rd choice.  Please check in my answer :)

Comment: @AdrianShum I've edited my comment to read "Here are two options:" :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Be specific and efficient .

**Use a tight, quick, specific regex, if that's what you need**:

`(?<=«|« |"|" )word(?=»| »|"| ")`

This should do it.  Simple lookarounds that account for a single whitespace.  Easy to modify.  What you see is what you get.

- `(?<=«|« |"|" )` - Don't return this (positive lookbehind of 4 possibilities), but use it to match
- `word` - the word to return
- `(?=»| »|"| ")` - Don't return this (positive lookahead of 4 possibilities), but use it to match

There are **no** **groupings** involved with this.

```
This string     Returns This as \0 (or $0)
-----------     --------------------------
"word"              word
"word "             word
" word"             word
" word "            word
«word»              word
«word »             word
« word»             word
« word »            word
```

Comment: it will match things like `"word»` (but that's a problem in OP's problem too honestly...)

Comment: @AdrianShum indeed, but TBH it's up to the OP to be clear.  Tightening up the schema isn't my place.  That may be a valid match and extracting just word from the middle, in either case, presumably is the desired outcome.